# Replace link logo on website

Tags: jquery

I am working on simple script to replace logo on website. Problem is that logo is not a img. It < a > with background image. I am used to img but not link.

This is not working:

```
$("#hlogo a").css("background-image", "http://i.imgur.com/pszAeGh.png");
```

I do not want to see this logo so please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set background-image you should wrap the image location inside url( ).
Try this code:

```
$("#hlogo a").css("background-image", "url(http://i.imgur.com/pszAeGh.png"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I wrapped it in url( ) and worked!! There seems to be an issue... a little big, but I will try figure it out http://i.imgur.com/AkrVJpN.png